# First attempt at makefiles

Tags: c++, makefile

I am writing my <s>first</s> second makefile because I need to understand them before I can actually start my C++ project. Here's the files I'm trying to link:

/storage/emulated/0/cpptest/test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H_DEF
#define TEST_H_DEF

class Test {
    private:
        int value;
    public:
        Test(int);
        operator int();
        Test operator + (Test);
};

#endif
```

/storage/emulated/0/cpptest/test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"

Test::Test(int new_value):
    value(new_value) {}

Test::operator int() {
    return value;
}

Test Test::operator + (Test other) {
    return Test(value + int(other));
}
```

/storage/emulated/0/cpptest/main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

int main() {
    Test o1(12);
    Test o2(18);
    std::cout << int(o1) << '\n';
    std::cout << int(o2) << '\n';
    std::cout << int(o1 + o2) << std::endl;
}
```

And here's my attempt at a (maintainable) makefile:

```
CC = g++

default: test

#I'm actually using four spaces here on SO
test: main.o test.o
    $(CC) -o test main.o test.o

#my issue starts here: what does main.o depends on? My guess is main.cpp only (which is really /storage/emulated...main.cpp)
main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) -o main.o /storage/emulated/0/cpptest/main.cpp

#same with test.o
test.o: test.cpp
    $(CC) -o test.o /storage/emulated/0/cpptest/test.cpp
```

And then? Am I fine now? How do I handle the issue of test.h being updated without make knowing about it?

Also did I get the usage of .h and .cpp files right while writing my files?

Comment: If you are just trying to use c++ and not really fixed on makefiles I would recommend cmake instead of native makefiles. Makes a lot of things easier.

Comment: Concerning the .h dependency, does it work if the file is added to the `test.o` rule dependency ?

Comment: How would I be fixed on makefiles? Sorry to sound dumb but I didn't even know the usage of makefiles until this morning :/ What are the advantages of each one?

Comment: @Pierre IDK should I try? Isn't it also a dependancy of `main.o` then?

Comment: @user6245072 The main advantage of a handwritten Makefile is that you can spend a ton of time writing it before you need to worry about your actual task. ;) Joke aside, if no one is stopping you (boss, teacher) and CMake works on your system (like normal Linux distros, Windows, Mac-stuff), save yourself the hassle and use it (or some other build system you like more, but CMake is most certainly not a bad choice).

Comment: @Baum mit Augen oh cool

Comment: No, seriously, what are the reasons to stick to standard make?

Comment: @user6245072 The main reason for using standard make is old legacy make scripts that no one wants to refactor.

Comment: Ok then. Issue solved 'til I encounter a new one with cmake. Should I close the question?

Comment: Btw, the hard coded paths are a terrible idea too, this is completely unportable. You can't even rename you project folder like this, let alone ship to another system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gcc can generate dependencies for you. So rather than manually typing out what all dependencies your source files have (which will inevitably be wrong or incomplete), use the compiler:

```
default: test
.PHONY : default

compiler := g++
objects  := main.o test.o
depends  := $(objects:.o=.d)

# include the depends rules if they exist
-include $(depends)

# test depends on all the objects, compiled together
test : $(objects)
    $(compiler) -o $@ $^

# each object depends on its source file
# the recipe here will both compile the source file and generate its dependencies
%.o : %.cpp
    $(compiler) -o $@ -c $< -MP -MMD -MF $(@:.o=.d)
```

This will generate files for you named `main.d` and `test.d` which will contain makefile rules with the actual dependencies of `main.cpp` and `test.cpp`.

---

Whenever you're in doubt about the validity of your makefiles, it's always helpful to run `make -pn` and examine everything that's printed there. That will help make sure your dependencies are entirely the way they should be.

For example, the first time you compile, the `*.d` files won't exist, so the `include $(depends)` command will fail (silently because of `-include`), and this makefile creates a dependency graph that looks like:

[image]

You should read this as any node needs to have its recipes rerun if any of its children have been updated (I filled in `default` blue because it's a phony rule.). So `main.o` needs to be recompiled whenever `main.cpp` gets updated. Note that there is no dependency on `test.h`! This may seem like a mistake, but we have to recompile everything anyway, so we're not missing out. After we compile the first time, we'll have generated the `*.d` files and then we bring those into our include, and the new dependency graph looks like:

[image]

which is exactly what we want.

Comment: Well ... not exactly the fist thing you do while learning make, but that's almost universal!

Comment: This is a little more advanced than what I was looking for, but it's still nice to know. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @user6245072 I'm afraid you'll have to put up with "advanced" stuff like this if you are going to use Make, the manual approach from the other answer gets unmaintainable for any non-trivial project.

Comment: @user6245072 There isn't anything particularly "advanced" in here. The only complicated part is knowing that those [preprocessor options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) exist for gcc. The [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) are admittedly cryptic, but they're very common.

Comment: @user6245072 In any case, I added some pictures. Because everybody likes pictures.

Comment: Well now I can't help but accept your answer. I still need some time to process those `$@`s and `$<`, but however. One last thing. I noticed that in the recipe for main.o and test.o, I need to put the -c flag. Is that normal? Why exactly?

Comment: @user6245072 `-c` means don't link. You're going to do that yourself later.

Answer (score 1):

The dependency of test.h is for both test.cpp and main cpp:

```
CC = g++

default: test

test: main.o test.o
    $(CC) -o test main.o test.o

main.o: main.cpp test.h
    $(CC) -o main.o /storage/emulated/0/cpptest/main.cpp

test.o: test.cpp test.h
    $(CC) -o test.o /storage/emulated/0/cpptest/test.cpp
```

The idea is that if something changes within `test.h` both `test.o` and `main.o` must be remade.

Comment: Can downvoters specify what is wrong inside here? I know ther eare beter way, but also consider the starting point of the OP.

Comment: Sure. Considering OP's starting point, it is a bad idea to just through a completely unmaintainable "solution" at him like it will get him anywhere. This makes this answer *"not useful"* -> dv.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Not everyone write as a first program the Apollo11 misson controller!

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia But there are quite a few people working on projects with more than one header file.